# Boot-loop after flashing custom ROM. What went wrong in procedure?

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I tried to flash a custom ROM on my old  Samsung GT-I8190N. It's the first time so I need some advice. The steps I followed are as follows:

- I downloaded the ROM zip file Jellybean 4.1.2 (CyanogenMod 10) 20130727
- I installed Heimdall on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine
- I turned on the device on Development mode with Volume Down + Home + Start Button
- I connected the device to my Ubuntu machine
- I ran in terminal `heimdall detect` and got back the message 'Device detected'
- I ran the command `heimdall print-pit` and I got the list of ROM partitions
- I extracted the files included in the ROM zip file and got the following files and folders:

  - folder 'META-INF`
  - folder 'system'
  - file boot.img
- As I did not know how to flash the ROM I checked some tutorials. I then checked the PIT file and noticed that there was a file called boot.img in the partition called kernel. So I decided to flash the ROM in that partition.
- I navigated to the folder where I unzipped the ROM zip file ran the command `heimdall flash --Kernel boot.img`
- the device rebooted but went into a boot loop

I know I did something wrong and I would like to know if I can still fix the problem. In particular I would like to know in what partition I should flash the boot.img file that I get from the ROM zip file.

When I start the device in Development mode I now get the following info:

```
ODIN MODE
Product Name: GT-I8190N
Custom Binary Download: Yes (2 counts)
Current Binary: Custom
System Status: Official
```

When I run the command `heimdall print-pit` I get the following output:

```
Heimdall v1.4.0
[removed irrelevant info]
Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Attempt failed. Detaching driver...
Claiming interface again...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Entry Count: 25
Unknown 1: 1598902083
Unknown 2: 844251476
Unknown 3: 28519
Unknown 4: 25708
Unknown 5: 28261
Unknown 6: 0
Unknown 7: 0
Unknown 8: 0


--- Entry #0 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 1
Attributes: 2 (STL Read-Only)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 0
Partition Block Count: 256
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: MBR,GPT
Flash Filename: 
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #1 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 2
Attributes: 2 (STL Read-Only)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 256
Partition Block Count: 768
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: MasterTOC
Flash Filename: STE_boot.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #2 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 70
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 1024
Partition Block Count: 2048
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: PIT
Flash Filename: goldenxx.pit
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #3 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 71
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 6144
Partition Block Count: 2048
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: MD5HDR
Flash Filename: md5.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #4 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 3
Attributes: 2 (STL Read-Only)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 8192
Partition Block Count: 1024
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: STEboot1
Flash Filename: STE_boot1.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #5 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 4
Attributes: 2 (STL Read-Only)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 9216
Partition Block Count: 1024
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: STEboot2
Flash Filename: STE_boot2.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #6 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 5
Attributes: 2 (STL Read-Only)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 10240
Partition Block Count: 1024
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: Dnt
Flash Filename: dnt.ssw
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #7 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 6
Attributes: 2 (STL Read-Only)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 11264
Partition Block Count: 1024
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: reserved
Flash Filename: 
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #8 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 7
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 16384
Partition Block Count: 2048
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: CSPSAFS
Flash Filename: cspsa.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #9 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 8
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 18432
Partition Block Count: 2048
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: CSPSAFS2
Flash Filename: cspsa2.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #10 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 9
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 20480
Partition Block Count: 32768
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: EFS
Flash Filename: EFS.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #11 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 10
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 53248
Partition Block Count: 32768
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: ModemFS
Flash Filename: modemfs.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #12 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 11
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 86016
Partition Block Count: 32768
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: ModemFS2
Flash Filename: modemfs2.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #13 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 12
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 118784
Partition Block Count: 102400
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: Fota
Flash Filename: ssgtest.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #14 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 13
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 380928
Partition Block Count: 128
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: IPL Modem
Flash Filename: ipl.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #15 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 14
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 385024
Partition Block Count: 28672
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: Modem
Flash Filename: modem.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #16 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 15
Attributes: 2 (STL Read-Only)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 417792
Partition Block Count: 4096
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: Loke4
Flash Filename: normal.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #17 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 16
Attributes: 2 (STL Read-Only)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 421888
Partition Block Count: 4096
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: 2ndLoke4
Flash Filename: normal2.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #18 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 17
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 425984
Partition Block Count: 32768
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: PARAM
Flash Filename: param.lfs
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #19 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 18
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 458752
Partition Block Count: 32768
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: Kernel
Flash Filename: boot.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #20 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 19
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 491520
Partition Block Count: 32768
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: Kernel2
Flash Filename: recovery.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #21 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 20
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 524288
Partition Block Count: 2457600
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: SYSTEM
Flash Filename: system.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #22 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 21
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 2981888
Partition Block Count: 1720320
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: CACHEFS
Flash Filename: cache.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #23 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 22
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 4702208
Partition Block Count: 655360
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: HIDDEN
Flash Filename: hidden.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #24 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 23
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 5357568
Partition Block Count: 0
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: DATAFS
Flash Filename: userdata.img
FOTA Filename: remained

Ending session...
Releasing device interface...
Re-attaching kernel driver...
```